# Store the value returned by the prompt function inside a variable called currentPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, function

How I can store the value returned by the prompt function inside a variable called `currentPlayer`

I've done this so far but I could not understand what to do next

```js
function prompt (X = 1, O = 2) {
    var currentPlayer;  
}
```

Comment: do you want to implement recursion?

Comment: You already mention that returned by prompt function . so you need return in function . Then use `var currentPlayer = prompt();`

Comment: I just need to store the value returned by the prompt function inside a variable

Comment: By the way you cant use `prompt` as function name coz it is builtin function name

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

[Prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) will return the value entered by the user.

```js
function getValue() {
  console.log('here');
  var promptValue = prompt("Enter the value", "Placeholder value");
  if (promptValue != null) {
    alert("you entered:" + promptValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getValue()">click here...</button>
```